# bash non-array ${!name[@]} parameter expansion confusion

Tags: bash, shell

Given that the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) in section [`3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) says:

> ```
> ${!name[@]}
> ${!name[*]}
> ```
>
> If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in name. If name is not an array, expands to 0 if name is set and null otherwise. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each key expands to a separate word.

and

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

and

> ${parameter:+word}
>
> If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

Can someone explain the output from the following expansions to me:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ cat hm.sh
p() {
    printf "%-11s : f=%1s : " "$*" "$f"
    eval printf \'%1s :\\n\' "$@"
}

p '$f'
p '${!f[@]}'
p '${!f[@]:-b}'
echo "echo: ${!f[@]:-b} :"
p '${!f[@]:+b}'
echo "echo: ${!f[@]:+b} :"
f=f
p '$f'
p '${!f[@]}'
p '${!f[@]:-b}'
echo "echo: ${!f[@]:-b} :"
p '${!f[@]:+b}'
echo "echo: ${!f[@]:+b} :"
f=t
p '$f'
p '${!f[@]}'
p '${!f[@]:-b}'
echo "echo: ${!f[@]:-b} :"
p '${!f[@]:+b}'
echo "echo: ${!f[@]:+b} :"

$ bash hm.sh
$f          : f=  :   :
${!f[@]}    : f=  :   :
${!f[@]:-b} : f=  : b :
echo: b :
${!f[@]:+b} : f=  :   :
echo:  :
$f          : f=f : f :
${!f[@]}    : f=f : 0 :
${!f[@]:-b} : f=f : f :
echo: f :
${!f[@]:+b} : f=f : b :
echo: b :
$f          : f=t : t :
${!f[@]}    : f=t : 0 :
${!f[@]:-b} : f=t : b :
echo: b :
${!f[@]:+b} : f=t :   :
echo:  :
```

That is why do the *contents* of the variable in question change how the `${!name[@]:-default}` and `${!name[@]:+alt}` expansions expand when the contents do **not** change how the `${!name[@]}` expansion itself expands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the syntax `${!f[@]}`, the parameter expansion is being parsed as a "list the keys" expression, which is one of the specific exceptions to the rule that `{!` introduces a level of indirection. The syntax `${!f[@]:-b}` does not match that pattern (because it ends with `:-b`), so the `!` *is* interpreted as an indirect reference, and consequently it is the variable whose *name* is the value of `f` which is being tested by the default value modifier.

The interesting question is, "what does the `[@]` modify in that expression?" It seems to be modifying `f`, which does nothing when `f` is a scalar but produces an invalid name when `f` is an array of more than one element; in that case, the default value substitution seems to occur.

My best guess is that this is an undocumented and possibly unintended corner case of parameter expansion.

Comment: Ah, you are suggesting that the shell is doing `${!f[@]:-b}` -> `${f[@]:-b}` and `${!f[@]:-b}` -> `${t[@]:-b}` and then (effectively) ignoring the `[@]` as `${not_array[@]}` is the same as `${not_array}` and then seeing `${f:-b}` or `${t:-b}`? This isn't the first time I've wished for a step-by-step expansion debugging flag in the shell.

Comment: @EtanReisner: If in your test you set `f=t t=u`, what do you see? But I don't know that the `[@]` is being ignored, exactly. It seems to be ignored only in the case where `f` is a scalar. Afaics, if f is an array, even of one element, the indirection fails and the default value is substituted.

Comment: `t`, `0`, `u`, `b` for the four expansions, which fits your explanation. And yes, I was specifically talking about the scalar/non-array case for `[@]` being ignored (which I also don't understand but that's a different issue). The array case is normal values expansion (which fits with what you saw and what I would expect). I haven't tried this indirection/expansion with arrays because that wasn't what I was playing with at the time.

Comment: Yeah, I think I was confusing myself. If `f` is an array, and you set `f=value`, you are actually assigning `f[0]`, rather than turning `f` back into a scalar. I think I knew that in some dusty corner of my mind, but it didn't warn me when I was testing your expression.

Comment: So I just tested the same expansions *without* `[@]` and the results are the same (obviously with `0` -> `t`, etc. in the `${!f}` case. So it seems you are right (not that I'm surprised). I was hoping you'd notice my question so I didn't have to go poking at the parser or anything crazy like that. =)

Comment: But now I do have to wonder how easy it would be to make bash give me expansion-by-expansion debugging output.